# How to declare a needed event in an interface?

Tags: c#

My console application must be able to get data from two different datasources that must implement an interface named `IDataSource`. When data are received the dataSource object must raise an event named `OnHistoricalDataReceived`.

I created the `EventArgs`:

```
public class HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public IDataSource DataSource {get; set;}
    public string Symbol {get; set;}
    public List<DailyPrice> Data {get;set;}

    public HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs(IDataSource dataSource, string symbol, List<DailyPrice> data)
    {
        DataSource = dataSource;
        Symbol = symbol;
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

I created the interface `IDataSource`:

```
public interface IDataSource
{
    event EventHandler<HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs> OnHistoricalDataReceived;
    List<DailyPrice> RequestHistoricalData(string symbol, List<PriceField> fields, DateTime? firstDate=null, DateTime? lastDate=null);
}
```

Then I created two simple classes, one for Bloomberg and one for Reuters:

```
public class Bloomberg: IDataSource
{
    public delegate void HistoricalDataReceivedEventRaiser(HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs args);
    public event HistoricalDataReceivedEventRaiser OnHistoricalDataReceived;

    public List<DailyPrice> RequestHistoricalData(string symbol, List<PriceField> fields, DateTime? firstDate=null, DateTime? lastDate=null)
    {
    var data = new List<DailyPrice>(); 

    // ... get the data

    var args = new HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs(dataSource: this, symbol: symbol, data: data);
        if (OnHistoricalDataReceived!=null)
        {
            OnHistoricalDataReceived(args);
        }
    }
}

public class Reuters: IDataSource
{
    public delegate void HistoricalDataReceivedEventRaiser(HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs args);
    public event HistoricalDataReceivedEventRaiser OnHistoricalDataReceived;

    public List<DailyPrice> RequestHistoricalData(string symbol, List<PriceField> fields, DateTime? firstDate=null, DateTime? lastDate=null)
    {
        var data = new List<DailyPrice>(); 

    // ... get the data

    var args = new HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs(dataSource: this, symbol: symbol, data: data);
        if (OnHistoricalDataReceived!=null)
        {
            OnHistoricalDataReceived(args);
        }
    }
}
```

All the code work If I avoid to put this line in my interface:

```
event EventHandler<HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs> OnHistoricalDataReceived;
```

But I want that every object that implements the interface will raise this event when the data are retrieved.

If I try to compile the compiler complains:

> *'Bloomberg' does not implement interface member 'IDataSource.OnHistoricalDataReceived'. 
>   'Bloomberg.OnHistoricalDataReceived' cannot implement
>   'IDataSource.OnHistoricalDataReceived' because it does not have the
>   matching return type of 'EventHandler'.*
>
> *'Reuters' does not implement interface member 'IDataSource.OnHistoricalDataReceived'. 
>   'Reuters.OnHistoricalDataReceived' cannot implement
>   'IDataSource.OnHistoricalDataReceived' because it does not have the
>   matching return type of 'EventHandler'.*

I tried many variation without any success. What is the right way to specify in my interface I want the `OnHistoricalDataReceived` event?

Comment: Your interface expects `EventHandler<...>`, while your classes use `HistoricalDataReceivedEventRaiser`. The types don't match.

Comment: Don't create a new delegate type in each instance. `OnHistoricalDataReceived` should be of type `EventHandler<HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs>`, just as the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *implement* the event in your classes, but instead you created *two new delegate types* and used them as the event's type.

You implement the event just like you declared it in the interface:

```
public class Bloomberg: IDataSource
{
    public event EventHandler<HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs> OnHistoricalDataReceived;

    public List<DailyPrice> RequestHistoricalData(string symbol, List<PriceField> fields, DateTime? firstDate=null, DateTime? lastDate=null)
    {
        var data = new List<DailyPrice>(); 

        // ... get the data

        var args = new HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs(dataSource: this, symbol: symbol, data: data);
        if (OnHistoricalDataReceived!=null)
        {
            OnHistoricalDataReceived(this, args); // use "this" as sender
        }
    }
}

public class Reuters: IDataSource
{
    public event EventHandler<HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs> OnHistoricalDataReceived;

    public List<DailyPrice> RequestHistoricalData(string symbol, List<PriceField> fields, DateTime? firstDate=null, DateTime? lastDate=null)
    {
        var data = new List<DailyPrice>(); 

        // ... get the data

        var args = new HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs(dataSource: this, symbol: symbol, data: data);
        if (OnHistoricalDataReceived!=null)
        {
            OnHistoricalDataReceived(this, args); // use this as sender
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** that (in C#6) you can do this:

```
OnHistoricalDataReceived?.Invoke(this, args);
```

This is thread-safe. Your current code can break if the event is unsubscribed by another thread again *after* the null-check.

Before C# 6 you should have done this:

```
var handler = OnHistoricalDataReceived; // save the reference
if (handler != null) handler(this, args); // use the local (unchanged) variable
```

Comment: I changed the code as suggested but now how can I tell in the caller code that IDataSource source.OnHistoricalDataReceived = some caller method?

Comment: @NicolaPrada just like any other event: `source.OnHistoricalDataReceived += MyDataHandler;` where `MyDataHandler` is a method with signature `void MyDataHandler(object sender, HistoricalDataReceivedEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your interface to:

```
public interface IDataSource
{
    event HistoricalDataReceivedEventRaiser OnHistoricalDataReceived;
    List<DailyPrice> RequestHistoricalData(string symbol, List<PriceField> fields, DateTime? firstDate=null, DateTime? lastDate=null);
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work. There are two `HistoricalDataReceivedEventRaise` classes.